# Phrasal verb meaning "to get rid of someone by frightening him/her"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

Is there such a word? As in:

> He ***(word here)*** the robber.

"frighten off" maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Scare Away/Off
>
> - to frighten someone or something away from someone or something.
>
> *He put on a gruff exterior to scare everyone away from him. The bear scared away a lot of people from the campground.*

([TFD Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scare+away))

Or, perhaps,

> #### Spook
>
> - to make frightened or frantic; to startle into violent activity (as stampeding)

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spook))

I, personally, have used spooked often when describing an animal that has been scared, causing it to run away from me. Mainly when hunting.